# How can I manually remove a WINE program when the uninstaller doesn't work?

Tags: wine

Installed a windows program to directory Z:\, can't delete it using wine uninstaller, can't delete it from nautilus.

Is there a way to override?

Comment: Drive Z: is usually mapped to `/`, where you don't have permissions usually. Did you use `sudo` to install? Where in Z: did you install?

Comment: its in /<usr<games   and i used wine to install

Comment: I'm pretty certain you'd have to use `sudo` to get wine to install in `/usr/games`. Which folder in `/usr/games`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and `cd` to the wine `Z:\` drive (in my case it is `~/.wine/drive_c/`).

Now use `sudo rm filename`.

It will delete the file.

Comment: Yes you are right. For a beginner it may be hazardous . OK I have removed it from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `gksu nautilus`. It'll ask you to enter your password. Just type it. It'll then open up a files explorer. Try deleting it from there